# How to group by property mapped to another entity

Tags: java, jpa

I am building a query using the criteria query api to get the count of rows for a given property. However it does not properly work for entities whose property is mapped to another entity.

Here is the code:

```java
@Override
public Map<Object, Long> count(@NonNull String attribute) {
    Class<T> domainClass = getDomainClass();
    CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();

    CriteriaQuery<Tuple> criteria = cb.createTupleQuery();
    Root<T> root = criteria.from(domainClass);
    criteria.multiselect(root.get(attribute), cb.count(cb.literal(1)));
    criteria.groupBy(root.get(attribute));

    return entityManager.createQuery(criteria).getResultList().stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(tuple -> tuple.get(0), tuple -> tuple.get(1, Long.class)));
}
```

Given this entities:

```
public class City {
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
}

public class User {
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private String status;
    private City city;
}
```

When I group the entity `User`by `id`, `name` or `status` it works

And the generated sql looks like this:

```sql
select user_0.status, count(1) from user as user_0 group by user_0.status
```

But when I group by `city`, it does not work, because the generated sql includes all the properties of the mapped entity:

```sql
select
    user_0.city, count(1),
    city_0.id, city_0.name
from user as user_0
inner join city as city_0
    on city_0.id = user_0.city
group by user_0.city
```

Is there a simple way to get the expected result without modifying the mappings and not having to include all of the properties of the mapped entity in the group by?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say you group by city, do you literally mean `criteria.groupBy(root.get("city"))`? That implies a `JOIN` to the `City` entity table. You also fail to specify which property of `City` to group by, so I guess JPA assumes you mean all properties (after all, you're asking for the entire `city` property to be present in the result, so its properties *must* be a part of the `GROUP BY` to be selectable in SQL).

Assuming you don't want to retrieve all the `city` details, you might use `city.id` for the grouping explicitly, but that will still involve a `JOIN`. If you expect grouping by `city` to behave just like grouping by the other properties, you'll want to map the `city` FK column separately as a property:

```
@Column(name = "city", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private Long cityId;
```

...and group on that property instead. I don't know if that qualifies as 'modifying the mapping' by your standards, but I don't see a way around it.

Comment: As I see it, JPA does understand that the column to group by is the `city` of  the `User` entity given that it put it inthe first select and in the group by clause. However I realized that not telling it which properties to return is a valid argument to try to return all of the properties

Comment: However I'd prefer to make some logic to determine if it's a property mapped to an entity and then map by its id and return it

Comment: Doing that in a generic manner will not be easy while also operating on property strings rather than the static metamodel. You could introduce a `BaseEntity` or an `Identifiable` interface to differentiate between simple properties and entities, but you'll need reflection on `getDomainClass()` to access that information

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I was able to determine what the problem was and then made the generic method I talked about.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the generic implementation. Basically, I find the correct path to the property, this is, if the property is an association I get the primary id or the specified sub-property (using dots).

```java
@Override
public Map<Object, Long> count(@NonNull String property) {
    Class<T> domainClass = getDomainClass();
    CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();

    CriteriaQuery<Tuple> criteria = cb.createTupleQuery();
    Root<T> root = criteria.from(domainClass);
    Path<?> propertyPath = findPropertyPath(property, root);

    criteria.multiselect(propertyPath, cb.count(cb.literal(1)));
    criteria.groupBy(propertyPath);

    return entityManager.createQuery(criteria).getResultList().stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(tuple -> tuple.get(0), tuple -> tuple.get(1, Long.class)));
}

private static <T> boolean  hasAttribute(String attributeName, ManagedType<T> classMetadata) {
    return classMetadata.getAttributes().stream().anyMatch(attribute -> attribute.getName().equals(attributeName));
}

private Path<?> findPropertyPath(@NonNull String property, @NonNull Path<?> root) {
    Attribute<?, ?> attribute;
    JpaEntityInformation<?, ?> attributeMetadata;

    String subProperty = null;
    Metamodel metaModel = entityManager.getMetamodel();
    ManagedType<?> classMetadata = metaModel.managedType(root.getJavaType());

    if (property.contains(".")) {
        subProperty = property.substring(property.indexOf(".") + 1);
        property = property.substring(0, property.indexOf("."));
    }

    if (!hasAttribute(property, classMetadata)) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown property: " + property + " from entity " + classMetadata.getJavaType().getName());
    }

    root = root.get(property);
    attribute = classMetadata.getAttribute(property);

    if (attribute.isCollection()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid property: " + property + " from entity "
                + classMetadata.getJavaType().getName() + ", must not be a collection");
    }

    if (!attribute.isAssociation()) {
        return root;
    }

    if (StringUtils.isBlank(subProperty)) {
        attributeMetadata = JpaEntityInformationSupport.getEntityInformation(attribute.getJavaType(), em);
        return root.get(attributeMetadata.getIdAttribute().getName());
    }

    return findPropertyPath(subProperty, root);
}
```

Now I can map for any property of a children or its primary id if none is specified:

```sql
-- city or city.id will result in:
select
    user_0.city, count(1)
from user as user_0
group by user_0.city

-- city.name will result in:
select
    city_0.name, count(1),
from user as user_0
inner join city as city_0
    on city_0.id = user_0.city
group by city_0.name
```